# Stop Excel Form Auto Convert Date Time To Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In column A I have the value of: `A|` and in column B I have `23/04/2019  23:48:17`.

I am merging both of the columns with the formula `=A1&""&B1&`, yet the result I am getting is `A|43451.4670486111`. However, this result does not meet my expectations as I need the date and time formatting preserved.

Here is an example of the expected result: `A|23/04/2019  23:48:17`

I have 380 column to merge, How to stop Excel from converting date & time to number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you take a date and concatenate it, you convert it to a string. A date in Excel is nothing more than a number, so the string representation is also going to be a number.

You can use the `TEXT()` function to do what you need.

```
=$A1 & "" & TEXT($B1,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS")
```

Comment: or you format the new cell to display date and time

Comment: Many thanks to K. Davis for correcting my grammar, sorry my english is not good, I tried your formula and it's work! @Forward Ed I had tried that before and it didn't work

Comment: @budiman,  you would need to adjust your formula from being a concatenation of strings to being a math operation.  `=A1+B1`.  The date is stored as integers representing the number of days since 1900/01/01 (day 1) and the decimal is the time portion representing fraction of a day.  Having date and time as a number is usually more helpful as it allows you to use built in date time functions and chronological sorting.  However, the best method is the one that meets your needs and understanding.